# trouble publishing a grunt plugin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have made my first grunt plugin, and when I try to run `npm publish` I got an `need auth` error, so I run `npm adduser` and after writing my username and my password I got this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: default value must be string or number
npm ERR!     at read (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read/lib/read.js:15:11)
npm ERR!     at readEmail (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/adduser.js:96:3)
npm ERR!     at loop (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/adduser.js:33:20)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/adduser.js:89:5
npm ERR!     at Interface.onLine (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read/lib/read.js:111:5)
npm ERR!     at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
npm ERR!     at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
npm ERR!     at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't think my code is relevant to the "adduser" operation, but anyway, here is the code: https://github.com/enriquemorenotent/grunt-ini-file

Comment: You should probably post the relevant source code if you want any answers.

Comment: I didnt know the source code is relevant to adding a user. This is the code: https://github.com/enriquemorenotent/grunt-ini-file

Comment: It seems to make sense that if you think the error message is relevant, and the error message lists line numbers in the source code, then (some of) the source code must be relevant.

Comment: What I mean is that adding a user seems like a kind of operation that should be independent of my own code.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Interesting. You may need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known bug with npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4363

Update to the latest version of npm with: `npm install npm -g`

Then delete your `~/.npmrc` file. Finally run the `npm adduser` command again.